# Could not find cache store adapter for redis_store

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redis

I have Rails 3.1.3 app and trying to plug gem "redis" to it.

I've added following gem to Gemfile:

gem "redis-store"

Following this article, i've added following code to environments/development.rb:

```
config.gem "redis-store", :lib => "redis-store"
require "redis-store" # HACK
config.cache_store = :redis_store
```

The app won't start, complaining to cache_store:

/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/cache.rb:65:in `lookup_store': Could not find cache store adapter for redis_store (no such file to load -- active_support/cache/redis_store) (RuntimeError).

I've figured it out, including gem "redis-rails" instead of "redis-store", but i'm getting another error:

> /Users/AntonAL/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:143:in `gem': redis-store is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)

Keeping them both…

```
gem 'redis-store'
gem 'redis-rails'
```

…gives another error

```
…gems/redis-rails-0.0.0/lib/redis-rails/version.rb:1: Redis is not a module (TypeError)
    from …/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from …/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from …/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
    from …/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
    from …/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
    from …/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from …/gems/redis-rails-0.0.0/lib/redis-rails.rb:1
    from …/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from …/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from …/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from …/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
    from …/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from …/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from …/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:122:in `require'
    from …/config/application.rb:11
    from …/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:52:in `require'
    from …/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:52
    from …/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'
    from …/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:49
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6
```

Help, please!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try

```
gem 'redis-store', '~> 1.0.0'
```

Comment: Thanks, recently I also found a solution. I could specify version of "redis-store" that matches version of my rails environment.

Answer (score 11):

FYI... I had similar problems until I added all of the following to my Gemfile.  I am running Rails 3.2.3.

```
    gem 'redis'
    gem 'redis-store'
    gem 'redis-rails'
```

Comment: I had a similar issue with Rails 3.2.3. I replaced `gem 'redis-store'` with `gem 'redis-rails'` and everything was OK.

Comment: This is redundant- `redis-rails` includes the other two gems as dependencies

Answer (score 8):

This is all you need:

```
gem 'redis-rails' # Will install several other redis-* gems
```

(See: https://github.com/redis-store/redis-rails)

Answer (score 7):

I faced a similar problem with a Rails 5.2 app.

Turns out the problem was with the configuration of the cache store in `production.rb`. Rails guides indicates using `config.cache_store = :redis_cache_store, { url: ENV['REDIS_URL'] }`, but this is not correct.

What worked for me:

In Gemfile

```
gem 'redis-rails', '~> 5'
```

In `config/environments/production.rb`

```
config.cache_store = :redis_store, ENV['REDIS_URL']
```

Comment: Good call.  The documentaation on the Rails site for this was dead wrong.

Comment: If anyone is here because of Rails 5.2, please check the docs where it states that you should install the base redis library or even better, the hiredis implementation of the connection. https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-rediscachestore

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is what you meant in your comment, AntonAL - this is what worked for me:

```
gem 'redis-rails', RAILS_VERSION # Where RAILS_VERSION matches the version of your rails gem
```

Can't get any simpler than that :)

Comment: That these versions happen to be in sync is a coincidence.  Definitely not an advisable way to use a Gemfile.